# Karate - How to construct two tables, using lines from each to validate against the other

Tags: api, automated-tests, karate

I am a newbie at Karate and I need help with what seems to be a basic test. I want to do the following:

```
* table input
    |Name      | Status | Parameters            |
    |Google    | 200    |{'query': '#(random1)'}|
    |Bing      | 200    |{'query': '#(random2)'}|
    |DuckDuckGo| 200    |{'query': '#(random3)'}|

* table outputVal
    |Name    | Expected  | Actual  |
    |'Random'| Random1   | Random2 |
```

Now I want to basically take each line from input and validate against the one line in outputVal table. How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suggest you spend some more time going through the docs and examples, e.g. this one: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/search/dynamic-params.feature - then ask a new question with what you have tried